# How do I format text from Reddit on IFTTT?

Tags: facebook, if-this-then-that, reddit

Is there any way I could remove some words from the Reddit posts when trying to use IFTTT to post to Facebook?

As of now, I am trying to trigger the recipe for any new topics in a subreddit and then post it on a Facebook page. But if some words like “lol”, “lmao”, etc. appear in the Reddit post, I don't want them (just the words) to be posted on the Facebook page.

Is there any way of doing this?